# Can Intellij IDEA automatically replace Maven dependencies with module dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm working with a Java project in Intellij IDEA where we have a lot of internal, standalone, Maven dependencies.
I have the source code for these dependencies imported into my IDEA project as modules, but when I select *Go To* -> *Implementation(s)* on a class that is part of an internal Maven dependency (and that I have also imported as a module in my project) I'm navigated to a decompiled view of the class in the Maven dependency (jar) and not the source code file of that class that I imported as a module.

To solve this I need to do the following:

1. *Open Module Settings* on the module using the internal Maven dependency
2. Find and remove the internal Maven module in the *Dependencies* list
3. Add a new *Module Dependency* and then select the imported module that corresponds to the internal Maven dependency

Is there any way to have IDEA figuring out this automatically or do I have to do this manual procedure over and over?

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions in the answers below by creating a new empty project and importing the Maven projects (A -> B) as Maven modules starting with project A, then B. When this didn't work I tried the opposite, first B then A, but with no luck.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: The comment from frant.hartm worked for me. I just needed to reimport all the maven projects with the blue circle arrows.

Answer (score 5):

To add another maven project (that is not part of your main project) as a dependency:

1. open you main project
2. in Maven Projects Tool Window click on green + button and select pom.xml of a dependency
3. repeat 2 as required

Source:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven-projects-tool-window.html?search=maven%20project

Comment: If I select the pom.xml file of the other Maven project I cant select the OK button.

Comment: That means you have already added that module as a dependency, try "Reimport All Maven projects" (the blue circle arrows) and see if you can navigate in the source. If it doesn't work try starting from clean project (without any changes in Module settings).

Comment: What if the maven dep is actually actually a multi module Gradle project (so there's no pom.xml files)? It seems I made some progress by adding the root of that Gradle project as a module to the project, then added as a module dependency _of the module_ of my maven project which I want to use, the gradle submodule I wanted it to depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a maven module A which has module B as a dependency.
If you import both modules into one IntelliJ project, IntelliJ will automatically use the imported module B instead of the maven artifact from repository - but you must import it as a maven module.

If you then run some test or application via IntelliJ from module A, it will use it's own compiled classes from module B and not the maven artifact from repository, navigation in the code and everything else will work as expected.

If this does not work, then you should report a bug.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It will use the Maven dependency (jar) instead of module B.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest that you are using intellij incorrectly in this example.  If you are referring to your maven dependencies as intellij modules, it will get confused.

You should either:

1. Change these maven dependencies to be [maven modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).
2. Remove these intellij modules as intellij modules and [set up your maven build so you can download the source](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) from your maven dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but neither of these suggestions will really solve my problem.

1. The internal dependencies I'm referring to is standalone Maven projects (made that clear in my question) used by a various kinds of projects, thus it's not feasible to make these into Maven sub modules of my main Maven project.

2. This is of course an option, but that requires that we publish source code jars for all our internal dependencies which might not always be desirable.